# Simple textbox connected with button, SQL

Tags: sql, button, textbox

I need to make complicated form which includes textboxes and buttons. But I would like to learn how to do in on simple example. I am connecting to local SQL server with application written in visual basic.

How can I make very simple form, for example with first name and last name and with submit button, which sends those data to database? Here is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection
        ("Server=[...];Initial Catalog=[...]);

    }
```

Everything is fine with connection, but I need to insert data with textboxes and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=[...];Initial Catalog=[...]");
        conn.Open();         
        string sql = "INSERT INTO User (firstname,lastname)VALUES(@fname,@lname)";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        cmd.Parameters["@fname"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        cmd.Parameters["@fname"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```